Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') while tryying to convert first word of a string to uppercase
Solved. there was an issue with my array length in the earlier part of code. found it out when i logged splitSecondName.Thanks for the suggestion.
   //destructuring name after splitting them near underscore

   let [splitFirstName, splitSecondName] = roughName.split('_');
   //splitting a name given in first_secondname form
  

    let camCaseName =
      splitFirstName +
      splitSecondName[0].toUpperCase() +
      splitSecondName.slice(1);


I am getting the required result but also getting this
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

what have I done wrong?
tried adding chartAt(0) , also replace method. getting the same error even though the program is working

Okay, it's trying to "read 0" from splitSecondName, so log that and see if that has the value you expect.

What is roughName when you are getting the error?

it is an array having names in format first_second.
Looping it to change the format of each name element

I meant a specific example; what is its actual value? But arrays don't have a split() method.

thank you . actually solved it when i loged it. my loop was calculating an extra iteration. i found the problem . now to solution

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
